# Visual Basic Password Generator

Tags: .net, vb.net, passwords, generator

I have been tasked with creating a visual basic random password generator. I have come up with the below which works however its a bit crude with its password criteria. I would like each password it generates to have at least 1 number, uppercase and lowercase in it. However how I have coded this it will generate a random combination which quite often results in one of the criteria being missed out.

I have had a play myself and I was going to have three strings, one with uppercase, one with lower case and a third with numbers. Once it has one of each it will then generate the rest of the password using my code. This doesn't sound very clean and I have been having problems doing this.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction or assist with the code below. Passwords must be between 6 and 20 characters in length.

Thanks in advance

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox2.Text = GenerateCode()
    End Sub

    Private Function GenerateCode() As Object
        Dim intRnd As Object
        Dim intStep As Object
        Dim strName As Object
        Dim intNameLength As Object
        Dim intLength As Object
        Dim strInputString As Object
        strInputString = "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMEOPQRSTUWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

        intLength = Len(strInputString)

        Randomize()


        strName = ""

        'Check for valid numeric entry
        If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, intNameLength) And intNameLength >= 6 And intNameLength <= 20 Then
            For intStep = 1 To intNameLength
                intRnd = Int((intLength * Rnd()) + 1)

                strName = strName & Mid(strInputString, intRnd, 1)

            Next
            GenerateCode = strName
        Else
            TextBox1.Text =("Please enter a valid password length")
        End If

    End Function
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(TextBox2.Text)

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Enter
        TextBox1.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

========== UPDATE ==========

Right I have changed my code a little so I have now got three strings with the different characters in, 1 for uppers, one for lowers and one for numbers.

This enables me to have a checkbox functionality in the form which is a plus. I have played around with the code and it now generates passwords depending on what I select with the checkboxes which as I say is awesome however I cant always guarantee that if I select, number, upper and lower I will get a password that contains all three, and sometimes the password will only contain numbers even though all three boxes are checked.

In guessing this is something to do with the fact I'm just asking it to generate random password using the characters I give it, and there is no verification that it has used all three of the options.

Any help on this would be awesome. I am trying and I'm not just posting and hoping someone will do the work for me. If someone can point me in the right direction would be great.

Here is my new code.

```
Public Function GenerateCode()
    Dim intRnd As Integer
    Dim intStep As Integer = Nothing
    Dim strname As String
    Dim intlength As Integer
    Dim strinputstring As String = ""
    Dim Numbers As String = "12345678901234567890"
    Dim Lower As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzyz"
    Dim Upper As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZYZ"
    Dim intnamelength As Integer = 1


    If CheckBox1.Checked Then strinputstring &= Lower
    If CheckBox2.Checked Then strinputstring &= Numbers
    If CheckBox3.Checked Then strinputstring &= Upper

    intlength = Len(strinputstring)

    Integer.TryParse(NumericUpDown1.Text, intnamelength)

    Randomize()

    strname = ""

    For inStep = 1 To intnamelength

        intRnd = Int(Rnd() * intlength) + 1

        strname = strname & Mid(strinputstring, intRnd, 1)

    Next

    Return strname

End Function
```

Comment: What part are you having problems with? You question reads very much like **"please write the rest of my program"**. What **precisely** do you need help in achieving?

Comment: If the criteria requires elements of  upper, lower and numeral characters, store those each in their own pool.  Lumped together it is luck if they all show up. You havent thought it through. Also, you are generating a password no one likes or can remember, so they will just write it down somewhere which defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This doesn't rely on UI controls, nor does it use the legacy pre-NET VB functions. Instead, variables are passed to the generator so it is UI independent.  It also does not use `As Object` because strings are strings.

```
<Flags>
Private Enum PasswordParts
    Upper = 1
    Lower = 2
    Numerals = 4
    All = 7
End Enum

Private Shared RNG As New Random()
Private Shared Numerals As String = "0123456789"
Private Shared Upper As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZYZ"
Private Shared Lower As String = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzyz"

Private Function GeneratePassword(length As Int32, 
             Optional pwparts As PasswordParts = PasswordParts.All) As String
    Dim PWCharPool As String = ""
    Dim PW As New List(Of String)()

    ' check the requested length
    If length < 6 Then length = 6
    If length > 20 Then length = 20

    ' build the pool and add the first of required characters
    ' for assure minimum conformance
    If pwparts.HasFlag(PasswordParts.Lower) Then
        PW.Add(Lower(RNG.Next(0, Lower.Length)))
        PWCharPool &= Lower
    End If
    If pwparts.HasFlag(PasswordParts.Upper) Then
        PW.Add(Upper(RNG.Next(0, Upper.Length)))
        PWCharPool &= Upper
    End If
    If pwparts.HasFlag(PasswordParts.Numerals) Then
        PW.Add(Numerals(RNG.Next(0, Numerals.Length)))
        PWCharPool &= Numerals
    End If

    ' pick the rest of the elements
    For n As Int32 = PW.Count To length - 1
        PW.Add(PWCharPool(RNG.Next(0, PWCharPool.Length)))
    Next

    ' shuffle the result so that the
    ' first 1-3 chars are not predictable
    Shuffle(PW, RNG)
    ' create a string from the result
    Return String.Join("", PW)
End Function
```

- Note that there is no lower case `L` or upper case `O`.  Users *will* confuse these with `0` and `1`, so either remove them or the `0` and `1` (or both)
- If the requirements for at least 1 upper, lower and numeral are *hard*, then there is no real need for the `If` statements (not blocks): just always pick one from each list before you add them to the pool. You also would not need the `Enum` or param. I left them based on the code in the question

  - Note that you should add code to handle when they click *no* checkboxes before calling this method.
- A `StringBuilder` could be used in place of the `List(of String)`, but the strings are so short that it really doesn't save any time until you run it in a loop many, many times and even then the time saved is minuscule.

Testing it:

```
Dim enumValues = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(PasswordParts)).Cast(Of Int32)()

For n As Int32 = 1 To 1000
    Dim style = CType(enumValues(RNG.Next(0, 4)), PasswordParts)
    Dim pwLen = RNG.Next(6, 21)

    Dim PW = GeneratePassword(pwLen, style)

    ' get riled up if the length does not match
    Debug.Assert(PW.Length = pwLen)
    Console.WriteLine("style: {0}  pw: '{1}' (len={2})", style, PW, PW.Length)
Next
```

Sample output:

> style: Upper  pw: 'QFHGPLIEEYPRP' (len=13)
>   style: All  pw: 'Z9Y3CoW' (len=7)
>   style: Lower  pw: 'tyghanjzudhhorfmvjr' (len=19)
>   style: All  pw: 'XyY3q10N6S' (len=10)
>   style: Upper  pw: 'IOZGTTQTPCYLKGEFRZ' (len=18)
>   style: All  pw: '7t5CNMUM0GdWb' (len=13)
>   style: Upper  pw: 'YIFXHRKEICOHXEUX' (len=16)

Then, the helper to shuffle (which is somewhat optional):

```
' Standared FY shuffle for List(Of T)
Public Sub Shuffle(Of T)(items As List(Of T), rnd As Random)
    Dim temp As T
    Dim j As Int32

    For i As Int32 = items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        ' Pick an item for position i.
        j = rnd.Next(i + 1)

        ' Swap them.
        temp = items(i)
        items(i) = items(j)
        items(j) = temp
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

The big problem is that no one can remember such passwords, so they get taped to the monitor or bottom of the keyboard.  A better method is to let the user pick the PW and just verify that it conforms to whatever rules by checking the string they choose for length and content.  This would allow `my~MuffyDoodle123` or some such that the user can remember.  Perhaps force them to change it periodically and maybe add a `TrashCan` to store old PWs by user so they cannot reuse the same one within 6 or 9 months.

A way to auto-generate memorable PWs is using words.  Create a list of several thousand adjectives and adverbs and another list of a few thousand nouns (easier than it sounds - there are online generators), you can create alliterative combinations plus a special character:

> Rancid3Rain
>   Withered$Whisper
>   Creamy/Cotton
>   Enduring/Empire
>   Maximum7Mist
>   Greasy/Glory
>   Vaporized_Vision
>   Toxic!Tears
>   Angry!Abacus

The "hard" part is to use a centralized list and discard words as they are used so there can be no repeated words in generated passwords.  Only when one of the queues is getting low do you start over.

Comment: I like this. The hard part: I think you just compare the new password with existing passwords since you will have stored them in your database, and regenerate a new one before you send it to the user if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

Here is the basic idea.  If you want upper and lower case letters, then add the lower case letters to the string s.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim s As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    Dim r As New Random
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For i As Integer = 1 To 8
        Dim idx As Integer = r.Next(0, 35)
        sb.Append(s.Substring(idx, 1))
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString())
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

And this should replace all your old code

Answer (score 0):

Below is my shot at it. It works well for me so I believe it will for you, too.
It ensures your password has a mix of the 4 categories, ie:

1. Upper case
2. Lower case
3. Numeric
4. Special Characters

Minimum password length is 6 characters.

The first section picks a character from each of the 4 categories. Then the loop runs for the rest of the remaining number of characters required. Since the first 4 will be in the order of the listed categories, there is a shuffle code added after generating the password that performs random shuffling, therefore improving the randomness of the password.

```
Public Function GeneratePassword(Optional ByVal Len As Integer = 8)

    If Len < 6 Then 
       MsgBox("Minimum password length is 6 characters", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Minimum Length Reset")
       Len = 6
    End If

    Dim pass As String = String.Empty

    Dim nums As String() = "2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9".Split(" ") 'Omit 1 & 0
    Dim lettU As String() = "A B C D E F G H J K L M N P Q R S T U V W X Y Z".Split(" ") 'Omit i,I,o & O
    Dim lettL As String() = "A B C D E F G H J K M N P Q R S T U V W X Y Z".ToLower.Split(" ") 'Omit i,I,l, L,o & O
    Dim chars As String() = "(-) @ # $ % * {-} [-] - _ ^ < > + = ~ /\".Split(" ") 'omit ? / \ ( ) ' " . , ; : &

    Dim passRan() As Array = {nums, lettU, lettL, chars}

    Dim min As Integer = 0
    Dim max As Integer = passRan.Length 'this will include the length
    Dim rnd As Integer = 0

    Dim sb As New List(Of String)

    For l As Integer = 0 To Len - passRan.Length - 1
        'select the set to pick from ensuring you have a character from each set
        If l = 0 Then
            For p As Integer = 0 To passRan.Length - 1
                'pick a random position in the selected set
                max = passRan(p).Length
                rnd = GetRandom(min, max)
                sb.Add(passRan(p)(rnd))
            Next
        End If

        'select the set to pick from by random
        max = passRan.Length
        rnd = GetRandom(min, max)
        For p As Integer = 0 To passRan.Length - 1
            'pick a random position in the selected set
            If p = rnd Then
                max = passRan(p).Length
                rnd = GetRandom(min, max)
                sb.Add(passRan(p)(rnd))
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

    'shuffle the result
    Dim R As New List(Of String)
    R = sb.ToList
    For Int As Integer = 0 To Len - 1
        Dim curr As Integer = GetRandom(min, R.Count)
        pass &= R(curr)
        R.RemoveAt(curr)
    Next

    Return pass

End Function

Public Function GetRandom(ByVal Min As Integer, ByVal Max As Integer) As Integer
    Static Generator As System.Random = New System.Random()
    Return Generator.Next(Min, Max)
End Function
```

NB: To increase the number of available special characters, and complexity, I have used (-), [-] and {-} because they are difficult to read on their own, but may also be difficult if combined without a space in between. I also usually prefer to omit OoiIlL01 from my passwords to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of a password generator. Maybe somebody will find this useful. It consists of 2 functions, but you only call CreatePassword, which takes appropriate requirements as parameters. It also validates requirements until they are met. I’m sure there are other ways, but this works for me. You could add symbols but would have to modify the code. Say you want a password of 16 characters long, has at least 2 uppercase characters, at least 2 lowercase characters and at least 2 number characters. You'd call CreatePassword like this:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Dim MyPassword As String = CreatePassword(16, 2, 2, 2)
```

Here is the code I use for the CreatePassword function

```
Private Function CreatePassword(ByVal inlength As Integer, numUpperChars As Integer, numLowerChars As Integer, numNumberChars As Integer) As String
    Dim funcResult As String, validCount As Boolean
    Do
        validCount = True
        funcResult = GetAPasswordString(inlength)

        Dim upper As New Regex("[A-Z]")
        Dim lower As New Regex("[a-z]")
        Dim number As New Regex("[1-9]")

        ' Check for minimum number of occurrences.
        If upper.Matches(funcResult).Count < numUpperChars Then validCount = False
        If lower.Matches(funcResult).Count < numLowerChars Then validCount = False
        If number.Matches(funcResult).Count < numNumberChars Then validCount = False

    Loop Until validCount
    Return funcResult
End Function
```

The code for GetAPasswordString function

```
Private Function GetAPasswordString(ByVal length As Integer) As String
    ' excludes ambiguous characters i1I0Oo 
    Const ValidChars As String = "abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789"
    Dim result As New Text.StringBuilder
    Dim rnd As Random = New Random()

    While 0 < Math.Max(Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(length), length + 1)
        result.Append(ValidChars(rnd.[Next](ValidChars.Length)))
    End While
    Return result.ToString
End Function
```